# Powershell to compare csv's and apend information

Tags: powershell, csv, compare, append

I have two CSV files. One is "termlist" which changes every day. It has multiple headers that may or may not have any information in them, but also includes email address. The other CSV is "webccmaster". This has 2 columns: email address and the webcc it comes from. I am comparing the email address to that of the termlist. I would like the output to also display the webcc column but I think I am missing something. My code is as follows:

```
  if (Test-Path C:\Scripts\termlist.csv) 
  {
     $termlist = import-csv "c:\scripts\termlist.csv" -header("User Name", "Brazil_inst", "Emp Num", "Emp Name", "Email Address", "Term Dt", "Plant", "Deptt", "Location", 
      "Region", "Job Name", "Sup. Name", "Phone Number") | where-Object {$_."Email Address" -ne ''} | sort "Email Address"

  if (Test-Path C:\Scripts\masterwebcc.csv)
     {    
    $webcclist = import-csv "c:\scripts\masterwebcc.csv" | sort "Email Address" -unique
    Compare-Object $termlist $webcclist -property "Email Address" -IncludeEqual 

    Remove-Item "c:\scripts\termlist.csv"

    get-childitem C:\Users\josh\Downloads -include Consolidated*.xls -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}

      } else {Write-warning "C:\Scripts\masterwebcc does not exist"}

   } else { Write-warning "C:\Scripts\termlist does not exist"}
```

Read-Host -Prompt “Press Enter to exit”

I know I will want to get rid of the -unique constraint but that is in there for simplicity's sake at this point since I can't get the "webcc" column to display as well. I'm also wondering if there's a way to JUST show the items that it finds equal in both CSV's. Thanks for any help or tips you can give me.

Comment: _I think I am missing something_ What is wrong exactly? What is happening and what is supposed to happen? Sometimes things like this are better with sample data so we don't have to create our own environments for testing.

Comment: So $termlist will be a list of email addresses for all intents and purposes. $webcclist will be a list of email addresses and the site in which they originated which i have merged multiple csv's with email addresses in them and appended the name of the original csv. I would like in my compare-object statement to somehow also show that originating site column. This script works fine as it is printed, I just wanted you to be able to see what I'm doing currently.

Comment: So let me see if I understand correctly... for each item on the $termlist you want to find the matching item(s) on the $webcclist with the email address being the joining field? Then for each match append the webcc property to the associated entry on the $termlist?

Comment: That is exactly correct. It already compares based off email address and displays that information. I just want to also append the webcc column to those email addresses displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Join tables on email, Right?

TableA.csv:

```
mail@mail.net|SomethingAboutSite
```

TableB.csv:

```
mail@mail.net|Data1|Data2|Data3
```

Code like this

```
$EmailToSiteAssignment = @{}
Import-CSV -Path 'TableA.csv' -Header @('email','site') | ForEach-Object {$EmailToSiteAssignment[$_.email.Trim().toLower()]=$_.site}

$Result = @();
Import-CSV -Path 'TableB.csv' -Header @('email','data1','data2','data3') | ForEach-Object {$Result += @( $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'site' -Value $EmailToSiteAssignment[$_.email.Trim().ToLower()] ) }
```